# Significant-Change Location Service will use Wi-Fi or Mobile Data?

Tags: ios, swift

When use  Significant-Change Location Service it must use Wi-fi ? Without Wi-fi this service will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it should work but location mechanism is a bit complicated in iOS.

iOS devices uses a system called aGPS. Which relies on combination of gps, cellular, wi-fi, geofencing etc. Wi-fi is the fastest location update option for the location manager since you can get your accurate-enough information immediately. GPS is the most accurate one but it takes couple of minutes to lock and determine your location if you changed your location a lot since the last lock on.

So maybe you had an impression that when wi-fi is disabled significant change location service doesn't work but actually it does. At least this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 Yes as I explained.